# Changing Angular Material mat-dialog-content styles

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

In angular dialogs you can add `<mat-dialog-content>`, but is there any way to style this?

I tried:

```
.mat-dialog-content {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Though, these two work fine:

```
.mat-dialog-container {
    padding: 0px !important;
}

.mat-dialog-title {
    color: white;
    background-color: #F48043;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px 0px !important;
}
```

Any idea how to access that `<mat-dialog-content>`'s styles?

Answer (score 4):

There is official guideline how to do it: https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles
 E.g.

> For example, to remove the padding from a dialog:

```
// Add this to your global stylesheet after your theme setup
.myapp-no-padding-dialog .mat-dialog-container {   
  padding: 0;
}

this.dialog.open(MyDialogComponent, {panelClass: 'myapp-no-padding-dialog'})
```

> Since you are adding the styles to your
>   global stylesheet, it is good practice to scope them appropriately.
>   Try prefixing your selector with your app name or "custom". Also note
>   that the mat-dialog-container's padding is added by default via a
>   selector with specificity of 1. The customizing styles have a
>   specificity of 2, so they will always take precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Using the CSS in style.css or any global CSS file.

You have to declare it as important, otherwise, the material style will override it.

```
.mat-dialog-content {
    padding: 10px !important;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying this in inline style file? Try using it in style.css or any global css file.

Comment: I was using it in global style.css hey

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to style this from within your component's css file, it is because *mat-dialog-content* is not contained within your component's *host encapsulation*.

You can use ***::ng-deep*** on the class in order to pierce the encapsulation and style the element from within your component. Apparently, this is the Angular team's current solution.

```
::ng-deep .mat-dialog-content {
    padding: 10px !important;
}
```

Also, that will only target the element. After that, css's specificity rules will apply, so you will also need to add **!important** or create a rule that is *more specific* in order to override Material's default.

Comment: Hi @Ruklav-Nomad, any idea regarding the style leaks(adding same styles to other mat-dialogs) due to this?
`:host >>>` or `:host ::ng-deep` not working though